# Как комитить не все изменения VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Видел мельком такой процесс: в редакторе CLion (возможно и не в нем) изменили код, из гита открыли тот же файл для сравнения и напротив каждого изменения стояла стрелка или что то нажимали и по частям необходимые места вставляли в файлы, которые находятся на гите. Как такое на VS Code сделать? когда нужно не все комитить, а часть, которую нужно предварительно сравнить с предыдущим комитом

**UPD:** Фото результат выполнения команды `git add -i` и `path`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего не появляется после выбора 5 пункта

Фото результат выполнения команды `git add -p`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут появились изменения. И вот самый главный вопрос, как опытные программисты добавляют не все изменения, а например только нижний цикл `for`

Comment: это не во время коммита происходит, а во время конфликтов файлов. Если не нужно коммитить отдельные строки, то просто надо их rollback'нуть

Comment: это называется интерактивный коммит или коммит по частям (есть разные названия). в консоли можно через git add -i вызвать и выбирать какие части коммитить. В vscode такое тоже подвезли - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730585/how-can-i-commit-some-changes-to-a-file-but-not-others-in-vscode

Comment: Уже ближе! Спасибо!!! Выглядит немного по другому, но суть таже

Comment: Посмотрите на расширение GitLense, возможно там есть подходящий для Вас интерфейс (а я по старинке в консоли это делаю:) )

Comment: Спасибо! Мне кажется не удобно через консоль два файла сравнивать и применять комит или реверт к определенным местам

Comment: А никто файлы не сравнивает через консоль. Когда я делаю git add -i  гит мне показывает каждый кусок изменения и спрашивает - добавить/пропустить/разбить. Да, если перерефакторить весь проект, то будет конечно сложно в таком режиме (хотя и в гуи режиме будет не легко). если же эти изменения делали сами и только что  и они аккуратные, то будет достаточно просто.

Comment: Я попробовал прописать `git add -i` вывело, как понимаю, количество изменений и меню со списком возможных команд, а куски кода не было видно =(

Comment: В списке нужно выбрать команду patch, а потом файлы, тогда будут видны изменения. Если нужно просмотреть все файлы и все изменения, то есть короткая версия команды `git add -p`

Comment: Спасибо! Но непонятны некоторые моменты, их описал в вопросе и добавил скриншоты результатов